# VirtualBox's virtual machine refuses to shutdown

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and recently installed VirtualBox on which I installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit guest OS.

Everything runs smoothly until I found that I am not able to shutdown or reboot the virtual machine in a normal way (from within the guest OS). Whenever I do so, it just goes back to the login screen.

I have to use the VirtualBox's menu to force a shutdown. Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away with later versions of virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify "The normal way"?

Have you tried running:

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo init 0
```

from the terminal window within the guest OS?  If so could you post what happens?

Comment: `shutdown -P now`, `shutdown -h now`, `poweroff`, `halt -p`, ...

Comment: @tyblu I assume there is a sudo prepended for all these commands.  But there is a bug that has been confirmed for 11.10.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/882817

Comment: Hi Karlson, by normal way I mean clicking on the "Gear button" on the top right corner and select "Shutdown" and then either "Shutdown" or "Restart" brings me to the login screen. Yes I have tried "sudo reboot", same problem.